# Java prints "null" for String reference != to null

Tags: java, object, null, boolean

I have big code and such lines:

```
System.out.println(car.getName());
System.out.println(car.getName() == null);
```

First line print outs:
null

but second line print outs false, so null == null is false?

I have also tried `System.out.println(car.getName() == "null");` since getName returns String but same result

Comment: What is car.getName() returning? null or "null"?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(student.getName().equals("null"));`

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: what about System.out.println(student.getName().equals("null")); ??

Comment: It's returning a `String` value of `"null"`, which is indeed not the same as `null`.

Comment: so is it student or car? anyway, try car.getName().equals("null")

Comment: @vanza it returns String but on command line I see just since you never see " " when it's string null

Comment: Also try `System.out.println("null".equals(student.getName())`

Comment: I haven't made equals method but I will try

Comment: @Templar What do you mean "I haven't made equals method?"  What is the return type of `car.getName()`?  Is it `java.lang.String` or something else?

Comment: @JackEdmonds it's simple String and in my car class I haven't created instance method called equals

Comment: @Templar `String` has the `equals` method already implemented for you.  All you have to do is call it.

Comment: @JackEdmonds ah right, it's String's method, it returned true when I wrote System.out.println(car.getName().equals("null"))

Comment: every Object in java has equals(). Default implementation is equivalent to ==, while in String it's comparing String content.

Comment: @Templar: You have then a major design problem in your code. You should never store `null` as a string `"null"` if the intent is to represent "no value". Perhaps there's somewhere a `name = String.valueOf(someObj)` going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to String you need to use the `equals` method:

```
System.out.println("null".equals(car.getName());
```

if it actually returns the String "null" which is not the same as `null`.

Why using `equals` instead of `==`, I can't find a simpler explanation than this [one](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html):

> To compare Strings for equality, don't use ==. The == operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object. Two strings may be different objects, but have the same value (have exactly the same characters in them). Use the .equals() method to compare strings for equality.

Comment: That will throw a `NullPointerException` if it really returned `null`.

Comment: you're right, edited it as he stated that it was returning a String, thanks.

Comment: why `String a = "foo"` and `String b = "foo"` works with `a == b`?

Comment: @Templar This article makes a good explanation: http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/

Comment: @Templar Simply, it does't test the content but the Object equality in that case.

Comment: great article, never heard about intern() that's why it was confusing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, your code has something like this in it:

```
public String getName()
{
    return "null"; 
}
```

So, when you run your test,

```
System.out.println(car.getName() == null);
```

It is testing the string object `"null"`  with the value `null`, which is indeed false.

Answer (score 1):

The  result is "null"， not `null`, so your code will be:

```
System.out.println(car.getName().equals("null"));
```